# Meaning of 'go on to say (that)'

Tags: meaning

> I shall go on to say that there are more incidents than we would care to imagine throughout Europe

What does 'go on to say that' mean, and when is it largely used? It looks like a phrase for quoting.

Answer (score 1):

"Go on" is often used to mean "continue". If someone says something, they may just do that and then stop speaking, or they may go on to say another thing.